# Run a string as an instruction to build an email

Tags: c#, mysql, string, datatable, string-formatting

I have a table in which I save an ID and a rule like:

```
|  ID  | Rule                                 |
|------|--------------------------------------|
|  1   | firstname[0]+'.'+lastname+'@'+domain |
|  2   | firstname+'_'+lastname+'@'+domain    |
|  3   | lastname[0]+firstname+'@'+domain     |
```

My problem is: How can I get and analyze/execute that rule in my code? Because the cell is taken as a string and I don't know how to apply that rule to my variables or my code.

I was thinking about `String.Format`, but I don't know how to split a string taking just the first character with it.

If you could give me an advice or any better way to do this, I'd appreciate that because I'm completely lost.

Comment: Have you taken into consideration to use regular expressions?

Comment: Can you change the rule format or is it a given thing. If you are the one who is assigning the rules and can change them then you can change them to a "friendlier" string expression (e.g "{{firstname}}.{{lastname}}@{{domain}}")

Comment: @ShaiAharoni ok this is interesting. I'm the one who changes the rules and adds new ones. Could you tell me how can I take just the first character using your way? (If it's possible)

Comment: @JoseMMartin do your rules need to support only the first letter of the first/last name or any other character ? If you only need the first character then you can a specific placeholder for example {{firstname0}} or {{lasname0}}

Answer (score 1):

If that is C#, you could construct a LINQ Expression out of the parse tree from for example ANTLR, or if the format is *very* simple, regex.

You have to make these steps:

- Evaluate the incoming string using [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/). You could start off with the [C# grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4);
- [Build an expression from it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654267.aspx);
- [Run the expression](http://www.somethingorothersoft.com/2010/06/18/converting-an-expression-to-a-compiled-lambda/) giving the `firstname`, `domain`, etc. parameters.

Comment: Could I use a regex for the 3 rules from my example? I think the entire list of rules won't be so much harder than those 3. Else I will use ANTLR as you recommended me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that would do the trick, but you might want to look at [CSharpCodeProvier](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/304655). Never used it, but according to the examples, it seems to be capable of compiling code entered in a textbox.
The thing is that this solution generates an exe file that will be stored in your project folder. Even if you delete them after a successful compiling, that might not be the best option.